# How to compute a time series of pairwise correlations

Tags: r, correlation

I have a time series of multiple factors:

```
df = read.table(text="
    date        factor     stock    value
    30-Jun-17   DivYield    AAPL    0.05
    30-Jun-17   DivYield    GOOG    0.055
    30-Jun-17   DivYield    MSFT    0.02
    31-Jul-17   DivYield    AAPL    0.055
    31-Jul-17   DivYield    GOOG    0.05
    31-Jul-17   DivYield    MSFT    0.025
    30-Jun-17   PB          AAPL    12
    30-Jun-17   PB          GOOG    11
    30-Jun-17   PB          MSFT    16
    31-Jul-17   PB          AAPL    11
    31-Jul-17   PB          GOOG    12
    31-Jul-17   PB          MSFT    14
    30-Jun-17   ROE         AAPL    0.1
    30-Jun-17   ROE         GOOG    0.12
    30-Jun-17   ROE         MSFT    0.12
    31-Jul-17   ROE         AAPL    0.1
    31-Jul-17   ROE         GOOG    0.1
    31-Jul-17   ROE         MSFT    0.12
            ", header = TRUE)
df$date = lubridate::dmy(df$date)
```

I need to compute the pairwise correlations between factors, and I need to do it every day.  The result for Pearson correlations would look something like:

```
Date        Factor1  Factor2 Correlation.Time.Series
30-Jun-17   DivYield    PB      -0.998337488
30-Jun-17   DivYield    ROE     -0.381246426
30-Jun-17   PB          ROE     0.327326835
31-Jul-17   DivYield    PB      -0.984324138
31-Jul-17   DivYield    ROE     -0.987829161
31-Jul-17   PB          ROE     0.944911183
```

Any ideas on how to attack this one?

Here's my first attempt:

```
library(tidyverse)
df.spread = spread(df, key = factor, value = value)
first.attempt = df.spread %>%
    select(-stock) %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
    do(as.data.frame(cor(.[,-1])))
```

That seems to do it.  The problem is the output has no label showing me what the correlation is with:

```
        date   DivYield        PB         ROE
1 2017-06-30  1.0000000 -0.9983375 -0.3812464
2 2017-06-30 -0.9983375  1.0000000  0.3273268
3 2017-06-30 -0.3812464  0.3273268  1.0000000
4 2017-07-31  1.0000000 -0.9843241 -0.9878292
5 2017-07-31 -0.9843241  1.0000000  0.9449112
6 2017-07-31 -0.9878292  0.9449112  1.0000000
```

Comment: Turn your database into 3-dimensional array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `corrr` package. This along with a `mutate + map` combo will get you a column of rownames so you can match the correlation pairs.

```
df.spread %>%
  select(-stock) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(cor_tbls = map(data, ~corrr::correlate(.x))) %>%
  unnest(cor_tbls)
```

This gives you:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
        date  rowname   DivYield         PB        ROE
      <date>    <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 2017-06-30 DivYield         NA -0.9983375 -0.3812464
2 2017-06-30       PB -0.9983375         NA  0.3273268
3 2017-06-30      ROE -0.3812464  0.3273268         NA
4 2017-07-31 DivYield         NA -0.9843241 -0.9878292
5 2017-07-31       PB -0.9843241         NA  0.9449112
6 2017-07-31      ROE -0.9878292  0.9449112         NA
```